# How pass parameter to WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want pass parameter to WITH class something like this:

```
WITH sction(id) AS (
  SELECT q.value1
  FROM   Example q
  WHERE q.id=id )
```

is it possible?Anyone can help me?

Comment: no you cannot do that.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i need to create a function?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? I think you need to add context if you want a better answer than, "nope, you can't."

Comment: Why do you think so?  Please edit your question and provide more details - the table definitions, and what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: The item in brackets will be treated as the column list returned by the WITH clause. If you want a function, the syntax is `with function xyz(params...) ...;` (requires Oracle 12.1 or later).

Answer (score 4):

`WITH` factoring clause a.k.a. `CTE` (Common Table Expression) is what we some time ago used to call a "subquery". As such, it uses a `WHERE` clause which you can use to pass that "parameter". For example:

```
WITH sction AS 
  (SELECT q.id,
          q.value1
     FROM Example q
  )
SELECT * 
FROM sction
WHERE id = 125      --> "125" is that "parameter" you pass while selecting from SCTION CTE
```

---

As of a subquery I mentioned: that would have been

```
select *
from (
      select id, value1 from example    --> this is a CTE
     )
where id = 125
```

In `CTE`, it is moved "up", outside your "main" query.

Answer (score 0):

with sction as (select q.value1,q.id from example q )
  select * from sction where id = 1;